# Use VBA to list all URL address of a web page

Tags: vba, list, excel, web-scraping

I used the below code for loading the web site http://www.flashscore.com/soccer/england/premier-league/results/.

After I found and click on the "Show more matches" link, all the football matches are loaded in the browser.

The below code will give as results only the first half of matches, the events showed before pressing the "Show more matches" link.

My question is how can I list all the events URL adress?

```
Sub Test_Flashscore()

Dim URL As String
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
Dim dictObj As Object: Set dictObj = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim tRowID As String

URL = "http://www.flashscore.com/soccer/england/premier-league/results/"

With ie
    .navigate URL
    .Visible = True
    Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
    Set HTMLdoc = .document
End With


For Each objLink In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

   If Left(objLink.innerText, 4) = "Show" Or Left(objLink.innerText, 4) = "Arat" Then

        MsgBox "The link was founded!"
        objLink.Click

        Exit For

   End If

Next objLink


With HTMLdoc

    Set tblSet = .getElementById("fs-results")
    Set mTbl = tblSet.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0)
    Set tRows = mTbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    With dictObj
        'If if value is not yet in dictionary, store it.
        For Each tRow In tRows
            'Remove the first four (4) characters.
            tRowID = Mid(tRow.ID, 5)
            If Not .Exists(tRowID) Then
                .add tRowID, Empty
            End If
        Next tRow
    End With
End With

i = 14
For Each Key In dictObj

    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2) = "http://www.flashscore.com/" & Key & "/#match-summary"
    i = i + 1

Next Key

Set ie = Nothing
MsgBox "Process Completed"

End Sub
```

Comment: Seems like clicking the link is navigating to a new page, so you'd have to wait for it to load using a similar strategy to loading the initial page (READYSTATE_COMPLETE, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait a little while for the rest of the content to load - clicking the link fires off a GET request to the server, so that needs to return content and the content needs to be rendered on the page before you can grab it.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on that link takes you to fixtures. You can replace all that before dictionary with

```
.navigate "https://www.flashscore.com/football/england/premier-league/fixtures/"
```

---

That is:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.flashscore.com/football/england/premier-league/fixtures/"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        'other code...using dictionary
        '.Quit
    End With
End Sub
```